# How can I show notification count on UINavigation bar in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, font-awesome

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to show notification count on the fount Awesome button.
My code is like this

//Notificaation Icon Button...

```
UILabel *lablnotification =[[UILabel alloc] init];
//    lab.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FontAwesome" size:8];
//  lab.textColor =  [UIColor whiteColor];
lablnotification.text =  [NSString awesomeIcon:FaBell];

UIImage *listImage4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"notification.png"];
UIButton *listButton4 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
listButton4.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
[[listButton4 layer] setBorderWidth:0.5f];
listButton4.layer.borderColor =[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
listButton4.layer.cornerRadius = managementbtn.bounds.size.width / 3.4;// this value vary as per your desire
listButton4.clipsToBounds = YES;

UIFont *fontnotification = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FontAwesome" size:15.0];
UIColor *colornotification = [UIColor blueColor];

NSDictionary *attrsDictionarynotification = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:fontnotification,NSFontAttributeName,colornotification,NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
//  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:font,NSFontAttributeName,color,NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];

NSAttributedString *attributedStrnotification = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:lablnotification.text attributes:attrsDictionarynotification];



// get the image size and apply it to the button frame
CGRect listButton4Frame = listButton4.frame;
listButton4Frame.size = listImage4.size;
listButton4.frame = listButton4Frame;

[listButton4 setAttributedTitle:attributedStrnotification forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[listButton4 addTarget:self
                action:@selector(ActualNotificationClick:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *jobsButton4 =
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:listButton4];
```

Method

```
-(void)ActualNotificationClick:(id)sender
{
   if([CheckStringVersion isEqualToString:@"1"])
   {
       NotificationScreen *screen =[[NotificationScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"NotificationScreen" bundle:nil];
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:screen animated:YES];
   }
   else
   {
       CheckStringPopup=@"3";
       UIAlertView *alertPOP =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Update Require" message:@"App is up to date." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
       [alertPOP show];
   }
}
```

I need to show notification like this

[image]

How can I show it?
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

Create Bagde to display with x and y adjustable on view :

```
-(UILabel*)DisplayBagde:(CGFloat)x :(CGFloat)y : (NSString*)val{
    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [lbl setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10]];
    lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y,30,30)];//strikeWidth+10,strikeWidth+10)];
    lbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    lbl.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0f;
    lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    lbl.clipsToBounds = YES;
    lbl.text = val;
    return lbl;
}
```

Add Badge on navigationBar (set your x and y) :

```
UILabel *bagdeLabel = [self DisplayBagde:30 :10 :@"3"];  //Badge count = 3
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:bagdeLabel];
```

Comment: @SiddeshMhatra I need to show it on lablnotification.

Comment: add badge count what you want in `UILabel *bagdeLabel = [self DisplayBagde:30 :10 : "your notification count"];`

Comment: Pass your x and y coordinates (where u want to display on view) like for ur case x= btn.width-10 and y = 0 and notification count.

Answer (score 0):

try this :
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mibadgebutton

Then add to your viewcontroller

```html
MIBadgeButton *btn1 = [MIBadgeButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn1 setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 150, 64, 30)];
[btn1 setTitle:@"test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn1 setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn1 setBadgeString:@"244"];
[self.view addSubview:btn1];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy, just download and add "BBBadgeBarButtonItem.h" and "BBBadgeBarButtonItem.m" into your xcodeproject. Don't forget to import the header file wherever you need it :

https://github.com/TanguyAladenise/BBBadgeBarButtonItem